# Having error message shown when stored procedure insert statement has duplicate primary key or not successfull

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am using a stored procedure which inserts data in a table.
Now if I am inserting data with a primary key value which already exists in the table, then it should provide an error but currently it is taking me to this page

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 0

call spInsertabc('primary_key_value_which_already_exists','edd')

Filename: models/abc_model.php

Line Number: 46
```

I would like to return a proper message(such as “Cannot be inserted right now try again” or “Primary key already exists”) to the user along with the page on which he submitted the daa if there exists a similar primary key value or if there is an error when inserting data.

How can I achieve that?

I am using codeigniter 2.1.0

Comment: why don't you try to search for primary keys before inserting them in order to know if you can make that call or not? I think that it's better to see if you can make an action while developing that catching the errors.

Comment: My model function as requested by srini:  public function insert_abc($Id,$Name) { $query = $this->db->query("call spInsertabc(" . $this->db->escape($Id) . ",".$this->db->escape($Name) .")");  return $this->db->affected_rows($query);      }

Comment: Hi Patroklo: I need to catch this as I will be having more complicated insert stored procedures which will be cumbersome,and server to search for primary keys first

Comment: @Patroklo: Looking for the key first requires two round-trips to the database, and it requires the dbms to do more processing.  Application code has to handle other errors gracefully anyway, so it makes sense to handle PK errors the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You have attempted to use the ADD PRIMARY KEY clause of the ALTER TABLE command on a table that already has a primary key.

Remove the existing primary key first.

Comment: Did not get this statement "You have attempted to use the ADD PRIMARY KEY clause of the ALTER TABLE command " is my insert query calling the primary key clause of the alter table command , please explain,thanks

Comment: post your php

Line Number: 46

Comment: My model function as requested by srini: public function insert_abc($Id,$Name) { $query = $this->db->query("call spInsertabc(" . $this->db->escape($Id) . ",".$this->db->escape($Name) .")"); return $this->db->affected_rows($query); }

Comment: My Line Number: 46 is $query = $this->db->query("call spInsertabc(" . $this->db->escape($Id) . ",".$this->db->escape($Name) .")");